# git push won't push latest changes after I do a git reset

Tags: git, git-reset

I mistakenly did a `git reset --hard` on my repo thinking it behaved differently than it does, so then I did `git reflogs` and another `git reset` to restore the changes I accidentally deleted. Now my local repo is fine but for some reason when I push to the server, not all of my changes appear, even though I get a message saying that everything is up to date. How do I get these changes to the server? Right now I'm copying the entire repo with my changes into a brand new branch but there's got to be a better way...

Comment: What does it show on `git status`? Does it show that your local is ahead of your remote?

Comment: @Jeeter, even better `git status --ignored`.

Comment: @0andriy Good point, I didn't consider that OP could have accidentally ignored it

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing is taking my local changes, copying all the files that had been changed, making a new branch, and pasting the changes into the new branch and pushing that branch to the server.